# How to read this multi-format data in SAS?

Tags: import, dataset, sas

I have an odd dataset that I need to import into SAS, splitting the records into two tables depending on formatting, and dropping some records altogether. The data is structured as follows:

```
c Comment line 1
c Comment line 2
t lines init
a 'mme006'   M   8   99   15   '111 ME - RANDOLPH ST'
  path=no
    dwt=0.01  42427  ttf=1  us1=3  us2=0
    dwt=#0   42350  ttf=1  us1=1.8  us2=0  lay=3
    dwt=>0  42352  ttf=1  us1=0.5  us2=18.13
    42349  lay=3
a 'mme007'   M   8   99   15   '111 ME - RANDOLPH ST'
  path=no
    dwt=+0  42367  ttf=1  us1=0.6  us2=0
    dwt=0.01  42368  ttf=1  us1=0.6  us2=35.63 lay=3
    dwt=#0  42369  ttf=1  us1=0.3  us2=0
    42381  lay=3
```

Only the lines beginning with `a`, `dwt` or an integer need to be kept.

For the lines beginning with `a`, the desired output is a table like this, called "lines", which contains the first two non-`a` values in the row:

```
 name   | type
--------+------
 mme006 | M
 mme007 | M
```

For the `dwt`/integer rows, the table "itins" would look like so:

```
 anode | dwt  | ttf | us1 | us2   | lay
 ------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----
 42427 | 0.01 |   1 | 3.0 |  0.00 |
 42350 | #0   |   1 | 1.8 |  0.00 |   3
 42352 | >0   |   1 | 0.5 | 18.13 | 
 42349 |      |     |     |       |   3       <-- line starting with integer
 42367 | +0   |   1 | 0.6 |  0.00 |
 42368 | 0.01 |   1 | 0.6 | 35.63 |   3
 42369 | #0   |   1 | 0.3 |  0.00 |
 42381 |      |     |     |       |   3       <-- line starting with integer
```

The code I have so far is almost there, but not quite:

```
data lines itins;
  infile in1 missover;
  input @1 first $1. @;
      if first in ('c','t') then delete;
      else if first='a' then do;
        input name $ type $;
        output lines; end;
      else do;
        input @1 path=$ dwt=$ anode ttf= us1= us2= us3= lay=;
        if path='no' then delete;
        output itins; end;
```

The problems:

- The "lines" table is correct, except I can't get rid of the quotes around the "name" values (e.g. `'mme006'`)
- In the "itins" table, "ttf", "us1", and "us2" are being populated correctly. However, "anode" and "lay" are always null, and "dwt" has values like `#0  4236` and `0.01  42`, always 8 characters long, borrowing part of what *should* be in "anode".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're getting yourself into trouble mixing input methods here.  Ridding the quotes is easy (`dequote()`) but the other part I don't know that you can solve this way, since `anode` can't be read with named input.

Comment: Thanks for the `dequote()` tip! Any suggestions for alternative approaches that will allow `anode` to be imported without modifying the input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEQUOTE() will remove matched quotation marks.

Your problem with `dwt` is that you'll need to tell it what informat to use; so if dwt is four long, `:$4.` instead of just `$`.

However, anode is a problem.  The solution I came up with is:

```
data lines itins;
  infile in1 missover;
  input @1 first $1. @;
      if first in ('c','t') then delete;
      else if first='a' then do;
        input name $ type $;
        output lines; end;
      else do;
        input @1 path= $ @;
        if path='no' then delete;
        else do;
            if substr(_infile_,5,1)='d' then do;
                input dwt= :$12. ttf= us1= us2= us3= lay=;
                anode=input(scan(dwt,2,' '),best.);
                dwt=scan(dwt,1,' ');
                output itins; 
            end;
            else do;
                input @5 anode 5. lay=;
                output itins;
            end;
        end;
    end;

run;
```

Basically, check for plan first; then if it's not a plan row, check for the 'd' in dwt.  If that's present, read in a line like that, incorporating anode into dwt and then splitting it off later.  If it's not present, just read in anode and lay.

If dwt can have widths other than 2-4 such that it might need to be shorter, then this probably won't work, and you'll have to explicitly figure out the position of anode to read it in properly.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe, that seems to almost work. I'm getting an error for the `anode`+`lay=` lines, however, that appears (strangely) during the `if substr(_infile_,5,1)='d' then do` block: `NOTE: NAME, '42349  lay' is not defined.`

Comment: You'll need to fiddle with the if conditions, most likely. That's what the `if / else do;` is supposed to avoid: identify the rows that are just `anode+lay` and don't try to use the other input string on them.  It's possible the `lay=` on the previous line is searching for `lay` on the next line, I'm not entirely sure how that works.

Comment: The condition seems fine because the `anode`+`lay=` lines are subsequently read correctly by the `else` block, so the output table is actually complete. I'm very confused by this.

Comment: I think it's caused by the `lay=` on the previous line looking for the next field to read in (since it is in default `flowover`).  If you change it to `truncover` or `missover` it might work (I don't think anything else should be affected by that, but not sure).

Comment: Hmm, or not, it happens in `missover` also.  I'm not sure why SAS should be looking to the next line there - but I don't have that much experience with this style of input.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'll mark this as correct and add a note to my question if I can resolve the errors.

Comment: Sounds good.  I thought it might be related to reading in `path`, but that's also not the problem (if I take out the `=` and read it in normally it doesn't work.